# User.IsInRole() does not work right after role assignment, but does after re-login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

In a ASP.NET MVC 5 application I'm using Unity container to create OWIN/Identity objects and resolve all the dependencies.

The problem is when I register as a new user and assign him a role like this

```
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "NewUser");
...
await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

it actually creates a record in AspNetUserRoles table, but right after that if I check his role with `User.IsInRole("NewUser")` I get false, unless I log out and then log in again, then it is true.

I guess the problem could be with Identity objects (UserManager, RoleManager, etc.) lifetime management in Unity context.

UnityConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // DbContext
    container.RegisterType<DbContext, AppEntitiesDbContext>();
    container.RegisterType<AppIdentityDbContext>();

    // Identity
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
                new InjectionConstructor(typeof(AppIdentityDbContext)));

    container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
                new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

    container.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole>>(
                new InjectionConstructor(typeof(AppIdentityDbContext)));

     container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
     container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
     container.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>();
}
```

IdentityConfig.cs 
(I use `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyApp.IdentityConfig" />` in Web.config)

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.Resolve<AppIdentityDbContext>());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.Resolve<ApplicationSignInManager>());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.Resolve<ApplicationRoleManager>());

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This could depend on your classes lifecyle or on the Session, can you try to do Session.Abandon and restart a new session and check if you get the new role then?

Comment: I added `Session.Abandon();` after `await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` but it made no effect, unfortunately.

Comment: Configuring types' lifetime as Per Request also had no effect, it still needs re-login

Comment: The interesting thing is that right after the role assignment `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "NewUser")` returns true while `User.IsInRole("NewUser")` returns false at same place. What the heck is going on? What am I missing?

Comment: Up to now, I've detached OWIN from Unity and it's still the same behavior, so the problem is not with DI, but with OWIN itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because using anything from the `User` object (IPrincipal) is looking at the identity token of the user for the current HTTP request, not the persisted values of the user.

When you log in that token gets created from the roles and other claims. If you change the user's roles in the database the token needs to be recreated and set as the user's new identity.

When you change a part of the user's identity. Just invalidate the old token and re-issue an new one by signing them out/back in.

```
private async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I am trying to use this but got error AuthenticationManager does not contain definition for SignOut. Any help inthis regard

Comment: @MustafaSattar Make sure you are referencing an AuthenticatonManager object, not trying to reference the static class

Answer (score 0):

Once an user sign in, the some of user information (including current role) stored in the authentication cookie which is created part of the sign in process. This cookie and its information will not update unless if you force re-issue new cookie with newly added role.

So that you will not get newly added role information with `User.IsInRole("NewUser");` method.

You need to re-issue the cookie to have the request's user reflect the changes.

https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2295

Or you need to change your owin startup as follows to set `validationInterval` to 0. Then every request will hit the database to validate the cookie.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem with using the SecurityStampValidator is that if your roles are part of your stamp then the stamp will be different on a role change and the user will be prompted to log in again. I also don't think regenerating the identity at every request is a good idea.

Comment: I also agree with Shoe. Every request should check if the user IsInRole, with the System.Web.Security.RoleProvider this could be realised. But that's the "old" way of doing it? What would be a decent solution?

Comment: If you are using MVC, you can use User.IsInRole("RoleName") inside the controller. But the User is part of IPrincipal.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this problem (who couldn't get Shoe's solution working, like me), a slightly different approach uses `GenerateUserIdentityAsync`. This can be placed right in any controller code where you modify the user's roles.

```
    UserManager.AddToRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "NewUser");

    var updatedUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    var newIdentity = await updatedUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(newIdentity);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above didn't solve my problems. My problem get fixed by editing Shoe's answer. I put this code after role assignment .

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```